# Using gnome-do as a dock

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-do

I've recently removed the bottom toolbar, in Ubuntu, and replaced it with gnome-do, using the "Docky" theme.

Things looks nice, but I have a couple of questions :

1. The dock doesn't differentiate between a shortcut and the application itself when launched. What if I want to launch more than one time that app ? (ie. the console).
2. The dock shows all apps launched, not just the apps launched on that particular desktop. Can I change this behavior ? I haven't found it in the preferences.

[image: screenshot of gnome-do as a dock]

(image from the blog "OMG Ubuntu", http://d0od.blogspot.com/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use your middle mouse button, or right click it and press "Run".
2. No.

Answer (score 0):

In the Gnome-Do 0.8.2 preferences, on the Appearance tab, there's an option "Indicate Multiple Windows" that puts an extra mark under the dock icon when there are multiple instances running. Perhaps this would help you differentiate?